# TrackingFunction in Manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate, tracking

I use this `Manipulate` to generate a dynamic graphic:

```
Manipulate[pntx2=First[pt2]; pnty2=Last[pt2];
         Graphics[{{Red, Circle[]},
        {Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, pt2}]},
        {Point[{{0,pnty2}}]},
        {Dashed, Line[{{0,pnty2}, pt2},VertexColors->{Black, Black}]},
        {Thickness[0.015], Line[{{0,0},{0,pnty2}},VertexColors->{Cyan, Cyan}]}},
        Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2],
        {{pt2, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction ->((pt2 = Normalize[#]) &)}]
```

Can someone explain me what does `((pt2 = Normalize[#]) &)` exactly mean?

Comment: To expand further, it's a question of precedence: `(pt2 = Normalize[#] &)` is equivalent to `(pt2 = (Normalize[#] &))`. This would set `pt2` to the function `Normalize[#] &` (just once, when the `TrackingFunction` option was evaluated). Since the value of `var = rhs` is `rhs`, the option would be effectively the same as `TrackingFunction -> (Normalize[#] &)`, which would disable the movement of the `Locator`, since it does not update `pt2` whenever the `Locator` is moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pt2` is the point where your mouse tries to drag the traker (the small black cross & circle).

`((pt2 = Normalize[#]) &)` means that before being updated, the vector representing the point where you tried to drag the traker is normalized. This way the tracker remains on the red ring, for it was deffined having raius 1 by default.

If you deffined the ring with radius 2 you would need to change this line to `((pt2 = 2 Normalize[#]) &)`.

Also it would be good to update the starting position: `{pt2, 2 {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}`

A complete example:

```
Manipulate[pntx2 = First[pt2]; pnty2 = Last[pt2];
 Graphics[{{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}, {Thick, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, pt2}]}, {Point[{{0, pnty2}}]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{0, pnty2}, pt2}, 
     VertexColors -> {Black, Black}]}, {Thickness[0.015], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, pnty2}}, VertexColors -> {Cyan, Cyan}]}}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5/2], {{pt2, 2 {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((pt2 = 2 Normalize[#]) &)}]
```

Comment: @Kuba, sorry man, I rolled back your edit  for we both edited at the same time...

Comment: No worries ;) Thanks for taking your time to answer.